# Changing values in a numpy array takes to long

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a function in which I turn binary images [True, False] in to gray image [0, 255] such that they can be used for opencv function. However, I found out that this particular function takes almost the longest. Is there a way I can optimize this function?

```
def change_image(image):
  unique_values = np.unique(image)
  mean_unique = np.mean(unique_values)

  if 255 in unique_values:
      threshold_image = image > mean_unique
      return threshold_image

  if True in image:
      image = np.where(image==False, 0, 255)
      return image

  else:
      return image
```

Comment: I don't understand, isn't `image` supposed to be a binary array? Why do you check if it has 255 in it?

Comment: `image.astype(np.uint8) * 255` -- The cast turns booleans into 0s and 1s, the multiplication turns the 1s into 255s.

Comment: Your function converts a binary image to greyscale or converts a grayscale image to binary.  Is it only needed to go from binary to greyscale?

Comment: It needs to go both ways..

Answer (score 1):

To convert binary image to grayscale image, multiply the whole image by 255, so that [0, 1] maps to [0, 255].

Also, grayscale images might not contain 255, so the condition `255 in unique_values` is not a reliable test.